# `pgfmathresult` in a command

Tags: pgfplots

The following code doesn't work :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\newcommand\machin{
\pgfmathparse{1}
\pgfmathresult
}

\pgfmathsetmacro\truc{\machin}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how I could have my command `\machin` return a result that I could use in a `\pgfmathsetmacro`?

Thanks for your help

EDIT : I wanted to do something like :

```
\newcommand\longueur[4]{
\pgfmathparse{((#1-#3)^2+(#2-#4)^2)^0.5}
\pgfmathresult
}

\newcommand\setEchelle[6]{
\pgfmathsetmacro\Echelle{500*(#6)/3.6/\longueur{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `\pgfmathsetmacro\machin{1}`?

Comment: I made my example very simple but there is a more complicated calculation in `\pgfmathsetmacro` indeed

Comment: Have you tried `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{<name>}{<amount of parameters}{<calculations>}`? For example: `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{cake}{1}{\pgfmathparse{3+#1}\pgfmathresult}`.

Comment: can you give us your complicated computation? Because what you are doing cannot work since you are nesting macros in expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\longueur` in the argument to `\pgfmathsetmacro`, because the commands in `\pgfmathparse` are not expandable. Either you define a `\setlongueur` macro that uses `\pgfmathsetmacro` like in

```
\newcommand\setlongueur[4]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{((#1-#3)^2+(#2-#4)^2)^0.5}
}

\newcommand\setEchelle[6]{%
  \setlongueur{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Echelle{500*(#6)/3.6/\temp}
}
```

or you use a different approach with `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{xparse} % also loads expl3
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\longueur}{mmmm}
 {
  \fp_eval:n {((#1-#3)^2+(#2-#4)^2)^0.5}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setEchelle}{mmmmmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \Echelle
   {
    \fp_eval:n {500*(#6)/3.6/\longueur{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Full examples. First with the calc package of TikZ.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\newcommand\setlongueur[4]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{((#1-#3)^2+(#2-#4)^2)^0.5}
}

\newcommand\setEchelle[6]{%
  \setlongueur{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Echelle{500*(#6)/3.6/\temp}
}

\begin{document}

\setEchelle{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}\Echelle

\end{document}
```

This outputs

> 231.1417

Now the same with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\longueur}{mmmm}
 {
  \fp_eval:n {((#1-#3)^2+(#2-#4)^2)^0.5}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setEchelle}{mmmmmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \Echelle
   {
    \fp_eval:n {500*(#6)/3.6/\longueur{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setEchelle{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}\Echelle

\end{document}
```

This outputs

> 231.1250817605121

One can limit the number of decimal digits with `round`: with

```
\fp_eval:n {round(500*(#6)/3.6/\longueur{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5},4)}
```

you'd get

> 231.1251